# Are there conditions for a sum or difference of linear maps between the same spaces to be an isomorphism?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-space-isomorphism

Suppose we have two linear maps $L:V\rightarrow W$ and $M:V\rightarrow W$, where $\mbox{dim}\hspace{0.05cm}V=\mbox{dim}\hspace{0.05cm} W$ and $L$ is an isomorphism.  Are there any sufficient conditions we can place on $M$ to guarantee that $L-M$ is an isomorphism?

Comment: What do you have in mind?

Comment: Consider $L^{-1}(L-M)=1-L^{-1}M$.

Comment: Frank Science: I don't see how this equation advances the problem beyond the description.  Even if M was equal to L, then this equation would still hold, but L-M=L-L=0.

Comment: user25127: that's just it.  The playing field is wide-open and I'm trying to narrow it.

Comment: My intuition is it needs to be a nontrivial multiple of the other linear map.

Comment: Everybody can name you some trivial conditions which likely won't help you. So you need to be more precise. Is $V$ finite dimensional or a Banach space? Go for the Neumann series.

Comment: Alephnull: Thanks.  I don't know if this is a necessary condition, but it's certainly a non-trivial sufficient condition.

Comment: user25127: V is finite dimensional; in fact, in my application it appears as various de Rham cohomology groups on a closed manifold and L and M are Lefschetz maps associated to symplectic classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not complete solution, but just some interesting notes. I will work over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$. If we have $||L^{-1}M||<1$, then we can create an inverse, denoting $L^{-1}M=X$, by $(\sum_i X^i)L^{-1}$. Moreover, if $||M^{-1}L||<1$, the same aurguement applies. In particular, if we have $||L^{-1}||^{-1}<||M||$ or $||M^{-1}||^{-1}<||L||$. Sadly we can have $||M^{-1}||>||M||^{-1}$, so we cannot go much further with this route.

Note that it is clear than an inverse exists if and only if $char(L^{-1}M)(1)\neq 0$, so that failure is actually pretty rare, namely, there is only a finite number of values of $a$ such that $L-aM$ is not invertible.

Going a different direction, we note that $I-L$ is invertible if and only if $A(I-L)A^{-1}=I-ALA^{-1}$ is, so taking $L=diag(1, \gamma_1, \dots \gamma_n)$, $\gamma_1\neq 0$, we get a pretty large set of matrices without the condition.

Comment: @user26857 The matrix norm of the inverse of $M$.